# says my embedded ruby is nil or empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eruby

edit page: the first line of embedded ruby is giving me the trouble

**Edit Post**

```
<%= form_for @post do |f|%> (this line is the problem)
  <p> 
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>
  </p>
  <p>            
    <%= f.label :content %>
    <%= f.text_area :content%>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Update post"%>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Look at the `edit post`, is this the problem? it seems like i was doing
everthimg right and i just can't figure it out.

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @posts = Post.all 
   end 

   def show 
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end

   def new
      @post = Post.new(params[:id])
   end

   def create  
      @post = Post.new(post_params)

      if @post.save
         redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "your post was saved"
      else
         render "new"
      end
   end 

private

   def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
   end

   def edit
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   end
```

Comment: Have you initialized `@post` in your controller action? Did you check if it is `nil` ? Did you check if the record actually exists in db? If you find answers to these questions, you will have the solution to your problem.

Comment: how can you check if it is nil?

Comment: Why is your edit action private? That is the problem. Move it above the private call.

Comment: It worked, thank you! I just started coding four days ago, so im a little bit behind lol but thanks for the help bud!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `edit` action is not visible as it is `private` and is not executed. Hence `@post` is `nil`. Move it above the `private` call

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
end
```

Comment: Once ruby encounters `private`, all methods after that will be private, not just the one directly below the `private` command (unless it encounters a `protected` or `public` command later.) Best practice is to list all of your `private` methods together first (this doesn't require `private` -- that's the default), then your `protected` methods together and then all of your `private` methods together. This avoids each from appearing more than once and makes the code a lot less confusing.